# Why are dark matter and dark energy invisible?

Tags: electromagnetism, visible-light, dark-matter, dark-energy

I know that dark energy and dark matter do not emit or absorb light, but how exactly does that work on an atomic/subatomic level? What happens in an interaction between the dark matter/energy and photons? Do photons simply pass through dark matter or do we not yet know?

Apologies if this question is basic so please respond in accordance with the consideration that I'm not a physicist and my knowledge of particle physics is scarce.

Comment: Hi, the issue is that both dark matter and dark energy are postulated, no one has exactly proven their existence. In some sense, dark energy is assumed to be the cosmological constant in Einstein's field equations, to explain the accelerated expansion of the universe, and dark matter is postulated through galaxy rotation curves and halos, etc... But, no one knows exactly what they are supposed to be in terms of physical matter. There are numerous theories and ideas: WIMPs (for dark matter), viscous fluids (dark energy), etc...

Comment: Can we not hypothesis (supposing they exist) why they are invisible?

Comment: The current hypothesis with respect to dark matter is that these particles are weakly interacting, and non-baryonic, so they would not interact with photons, hence, remain invisible. Dark energy is a completely different postulation though: cosmological constant, scalar fields, viscous fluids, you name it, people have associated dark energy with it! (I'm also guilty of this in my own previous work :) )

Comment: Interesting :) If you'd be so kind, would you be able to write this up in an answer so I can accept it? And could you also explain how photons interest with respect to visible matter also?

Comment: Sure.... see answer below.

Comment: I lost loads of reputation recently by getting cheeky and asking whether the universe is a hologram or not     :p

Comment: I wonder why? Nothing wrong with being curious.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60071/discussion-between-charlie-and-ikjyot-singh-kohli).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue is that both dark matter and dark energy are postulated, no one has exactly proven their existence. In some sense, dark energy is assumed to be the cosmological constant in Einstein's field equations, to explain the accelerated expansion of the universe, and dark matter is postulated through galaxy rotation curves and halos, etc... But, no one knows exactly what they are supposed to be in terms of physical matter. There are numerous theories and ideas: WIMPs (for dark matter), viscous fluids (dark energy). 
The current hypothesis with respect to dark matter is that these particles are weakly interacting, and non-baryonic, so they would not interact with photons, hence, remain invisible. Dark energy is a completely different postulation though: cosmological constant, scalar fields, viscous fluids, you name it, people have associated dark energy with it! (I'm also guilty of this in my own previous work :) )

With respect to your second question, how photons interact with regular matter, these are just the standard photon interactions in particle physics. A famous example is that of Compton scattering between an electron and a photon. Any standard particle physics text would go through the standard photon-matter interactions, Griffith's elementary particles book is excellent for this.

Comment: "the issue is that both dark matter and dark energy are postulated, no one has exactly proven their existence. " I don't like this way of putting things. Technically they are observed. You observe galaxies rotation curves and see that in our current theories of gravitation, you can have such curves of rotation only if the galaxy has way more mass than what you see elecromagnetically. Where is the postulate? It's an observation followed by a conclusion.

Comment: I called it a postulate, because there is a difference between the validity of CDM models  or \Lambda-CDM models in how they are interpreted by Newtonian-motivated astrophysicists, and pure GR people like myself. A great deal behind the Lambda-CDM relies on FLRW models of the universe, and there are a lot of theories out there that give the same "output" without postulating the need for DM or DE. The most recent example is Verlinde's theory. GFR Ellis has also written about the Trace-Free EFE as an alternative to dark energy/cosmological constant.

Comment: If Verlinde theory, or any other theory of gravity, gives me the same right predictions and perfect matching with experiments that relativity gives me, plus they explain rotation curves and what we call today dark matter, I'd gladly accept them as the most elegant solution. If we use standard GR, we can't explain rotational curves, we need more mass. GR is the postulate, dark matter is a consequence of observations and their explanation in terms of the best theory of gravity we have so far. That's what I meant.

Comment: But, what do you mean by standard GR? There are cosmological models that do not explain rotational curves without dark matter, hence, the Lambda-CDM model. But, there are many, many, cosmological models. They have to be tested. There are inhomogeneous cosmologies such as Lemaitre-Tolman-Bondi and Swiss-Cheese models that all predict the structure of the universe we observe today that do not require dark energy for example, these have to be tested. There are very few tests currently of alternative cosmologies!

Comment: I can't say much about cosmology so I won't address that. As regards galaxies, we can't explain rotation curves, that's it. You give me a distribution of matter, let's say the flat disk of neutral hydrogen surrounding a galaxy and you predict how it should move under the influence of its autogravity and the gravity of the inner parts of the galaxy. You try to check your predictions with observation and you see observation don''t match them, they would if there was additional matter, that's it. With standard GR I just mean GR, not any kind of tentative to modify it. Sorry for my English

Comment: Like many astrophysicists, you are choosing to look at things very locally and ignoring the bigger picture, that's fine. But, local physics (galaxies, clusters, planets, etc...) is very much a consequence of large-structure physics via top-down causation. I don't know how one separates galaxies from cosmology, but Newtonian people do this all the time, so we G.R. people are in the minority I suppose.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60077/discussion-between-run-like-hell-and-ikjyot-singh-kohli).

Answer (score 0):

The "why" question I would answer as such:

Dark matter, if it exists, is matter that does not interact via the electromagnetic force (of which the force carrier particles are photons, hence it can not be "seen") and it does not interact via weak or strong force either.
Dark matter interacts gravitationally - this is how we suspect that it might exist. E.g. it would explain certain observations of which, imo, the most important one is the so called [bullet cluster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bullet_Cluster#Overview).

This a structure of two galaxies that have already passed through each other. We can have a good estimate of where the "visible mass" (interstellar gas, stars) are. And (e.g. from gravitational lens effect) we can infer, where the center of mass really is.
Most of the visible mass is the gas (this may be a surprise, but that's the way it is). The gas slowed down during the collision of the two galaxies and it stayed in the middle between the galaxies.

However most of the total mass is distributed as two blobs. It must have passed through each other. It did not interact electromagnetically (like the gas) but it takes part in gravity. 
How to explain this? Postulate some kind of matter that does not interact electromagnetically that could just pass through each other.

Of course this is somewhat a simplification. But it's the gist of the story.

Another thing that can be explained with dark matter is galaxy rotation curves (see the other answer) - but that could be explained by "Modified Newton Dynamics" aka "MOND" as well. Hence I think the bullet cluster is a very important example.